# Switching between the sheets periodically using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

What I am trying to achieve here is I have three different dashboards running in all the three sheet which I was to switch every 1 Min. I am stuck with the below code. Any help would be appreciated.

I have three sheets to switch between
1. First_sheet, 2. Second_Sheet, 3. Third_Sheet

```
Sub Swap_Sheets()

    Dim Sheets As Workbook
    Dim dTime As Date

    dTime = Now + TimeValue("00:00:60")

    Application.OnTime dTime, "Swap_Sheets"

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "First_Sheet" Then
        Sheets("Second_Sheet").Activate
    Else
        Sheets("Third_Sheet").Activate
    Else
        Sheets("First_Sheet").Activate
    End If

    If Sheets("Second_sheet").CheckBox1.Value = False Then
        Application.OnTime dTime, "Swap_Sheets", , False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what is your Problem? does the code not do what you want? does it throw an error? please be specific

Comment: You have two `Else` statements there !

Answer (score 0):

This is a good way to do it, avoiding multiple if-s,select case and recursion:

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Sub SwapSheets()

    Dim dTime       As Date
    Dim i           As Long: i = 1

    While i <= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        If ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name Then
            Worksheets(1).Activate
        Else
            Worksheets(ActiveSheet.index + 1).Activate
        End If
        i = i + 1
        Sleep (10000) '10 seconds
    Wend

End Sub
```

The idea is that every sheet has an index, and you simply have to increment the index of the active one. If the last sheet is the activeone, start from the beginning. Sleep takes milliseconds as a parameter, for 60 seconds it is 60.000.

Plus - in your code you have     `Dim Sheets As Workbook` and here you probably mean `Worksheet` (I am only guessing).

---

If you only want to activate 3 worksheets, this is probably the easiest way to do it:

```
Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Public Sub SwapSheets()

    Dim sheetNames()    As Variant
    Dim i               As Long

    sheetNames = Array("Sheet1Name", "Sheet2Name", "Sheet3Name")

    For i = LBound(sheetNames) To UBound(sheetNames)
        Sheets(sheetNames(i)).Activate
        Sleep (10000) '10 seconds
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Vityata,

Sorry for the delay in response, I tried above code but the sheets are not toggling. Basically what I am trying to achieve is I have three dashboards running on three different sheets of same excel workbook and it has more than 5-6 sheets out of which I want to toggle only first three sheets. who names are 1. First_sheet, 2. Second_Sheet, 3. Third_Sheet.

Regards,
RKP

Comment: Hi team, Could someone please help me with this.

Comment: Team is reporting here, the task is fulfilled, @RKP :)